# How to write a find query, that matched with specific field value in Node.js with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to define and manipulate mongoDB database in Node JS.
I have a model schema named 'product.js'

```
var schema = new Schema({
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productCategory: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Whenever I need all the products, I am using

```
 var products = Product.find(function (err, docs) { 
        //docs contains all products information
 });
```

But now it is required to get products of a specific category. Like I have a category name 'cat1' and I have to retrieve all the products, that's category matched with 'cat1'. It's mostly like,

```
var products = Product.find({productCategory: 'cat1'}function (err, docs) { 
        //docs contains all products of cat1 category
 });
```

So how can I get the products of a desired category?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any relationship between Product and Category in your schema. Given that Mongoose itself doesn't offer that feature, you may abandon the traditional SQL entity definition and embrace what a document store offers you: embed the category name/id inside the product object, so you can query it like you like.

That's the big win of using MongoDB: your documents can contain complex objects in addition to single values. See an example with a `Person` model that contains a `name` property which is itself and object with `first` and `last` inside it in the docs:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

The relevant query is

```
// find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields
Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation) // Space Ghost is a talk show host.
})
```

Notice the `'name.last`' criteria, it will ask Mongo to look **inside** the name property.

If you still want to define separate Product and Category models, you'll have to use a Mongoose plugin like `mongo-relation`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-relation